# installing Canon printer model PIXMA MG 2522

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

How to properly install Canon printer model PIXMA MG 2522 on EITHER Ubuntu 18.04 OR Ubuntu 20.10.  EITHER will suffice and make me happy !

Answer (score 1):

Bionic actually had canon printer drivers on my installation, (Gutenprint something or other...), but they don't work right on my MX340--the colors are all wrong.

So I was struggling with installing the cnijfilter V3.90 driver for MX 340, and found the answer here (it also has many other Canon drivers, including the MG2500):

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/canon-ij-printer-scangear-mp-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/

Steps are basically:

1. Remove any installed versions of cnijfilter you may have tried.

   To find old cnijfilter pkgs do

   ```
   sudo apt-cache policy cnijfilter*
   ```

   Then remove if any are installed

   ```
   sudo apt remove <your old cnijfilter pkgs>
   ```
2. Add the PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Open Package manager, search for cnijfilter, mark for install your printer (choose your printer model here).  Mine was the MX340:

   cnijfilter-mx340series:i386
4. Open printers gui, add printer, search for network printer and apply the cnijnet address that is found.

   cnijnet:/XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX (the X's will be the mac of your printer)
5. Make sure the Canon (your model) series Ver.3.90 driver shows in Make/model window -- not the Gutenprint driver.  (mine showed the correct driver: Canon MX340 series Ver.3.90).

If for some reason the Gutenprint driver shows instead, then go back and choose the Canon (your model) series Ver.3.90 driver in the make/model window.

Comment: This was the solution for me with a Pixma MG3120 on Ubuntu 18.04. I suspect previous mucking about didn't work because of a 32 vs 64 bit problem.